# Офис(,) ближайший к вам(,) находится

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли запятые?

`Наш офис(,) ближайший к вам(,) находится на станции «Чёрная речка».`

Ещё: как правильно писать – «Чёрная речка» или «Чёрная Речка»?

Comment: http://www.metro.spb.ru/uploads/document/stancii_adres_2020i.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Наш Офис, **ближайший к вАм**, находится на станции «Чёрная речка».*

**Пояснение**

1. Обособляется определительный оборот, стоящий **после** определяемого слова. Делается два ударения.

Сравнить: *Наш офис **из ближАйших к вам** / находится на станции «Чёрная речка»*.  Несогласованное определение в постпозиции может не обособляться. В данном случае обособление факультативное. Определение не будет обособляться, если оно является смысловым центром высказывания.

2. "Черная речка".  Река с таким названием **существует**. "Черная Речка". Реки с таким названием **нет.** (Так называется местность, где раньше была река.)

Comment: Не надо здесь же запятой! Вы сами на другой мой вопрос сказали, что, если прилагательное — это главная часть, запятая не нужна! Контекст такой, что у компании несколько офисов и что они говорям именно про тот, который самый близкий. Здесь нельзя изъять прилагательное.

Comment: Нельзя изъять, зато можно добавить: Наш Офис, КОТОРЫЙ ближе всего к вам,  находится...  Это если уж говорить на вашем языке: здесь вырезал – там приклеил, какая разница!  Это технический прием, у него ограниченная логика.  Я же заменяю придаточным определительным. Что касается темы обособления определений,  то изучите ее внимательнее, там много тонкостей.  Некорректно сочетание "наш офис ближайший к вам". здесь нельзя обойтись без обособления.

Comment: И еще. Если вам настолько не нравятся мои ответы, так что вы приемку возвращаете, то я постараюсь отвечать реже. Я трачу на них много времени, а вы обращаетесь с ними несколько небрежно.  Зачем я вообще отвечаю? Я понимаю те  неясные вопросы в темах,  о которых вы спрашиваете.  Они действительно достойны внимания. Но знаете, я ведь могу поступить иначе, если сотрудничество со мной вам больше не по душе. Как? Просто задать дополнительный вопрос по вашей же теме.  Но мне хотелось бы, чтобы мы дружили, а не противоречили друг другу.

Comment: Я тоже считаю, что обособление необходимо.

Comment: Просто я Розенталя прочитал, а там написано, что если оборот, имеющий прилагательное (не причастие!), — суть, то запятая не ставится. Вот я и хочу, чтобы вы свой выбор подтвердили, так как я уже ничего насчёт этих определений не понимаю: зашла речь о сравнительной форме — запятая не нужна, вы говорите; о превосходной — нужна, вы говорите. Мне нравятся ваши ответы, но я не хочу просто я принимать, не понимая, почему надо так!

Comment: Дайте ссылку на правило, где это написано. Нужно различать согласованные и несогласованные  определения, разные там правила. А для согласованных определений (причастий или прилагательных)  правила одинаковые.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр, приводите ссылку на правило, где говорится, что определение-прилагательное не обособляется. Иначе обсуждение не имеет смысла.