# Можно ли так изменить предложение, чтобы обособленный оборот стал необособленным?

Tags: пунктуация, определения

*Наш офис, **ближайший к вам**, находится на станции «Чёрная речка».*

В этом предложении оборот на основе согласованного определения стоит после определяемого слова и **обособляется**.  Можно ли так **перестроить** предложение, чтобы оборот в постпозиции стал **смысловым** центром высказывания и **не обособлялся** по правилу Розенталя?

Как решить эту задачу **только по правилам,** без использования интонационного анализа?

**Пояснение**

**Это предложении** из другого [вопроса](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475523/%D0%9E%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F). В ответе было указано, что оборот **обособляется**. Ответ был **принят**, но потом приемка была отозвана, так как у автора появились **сомнения** в правильности решения.

Как **доказать**, что оборот нужно **обособить** в этом случае, но при изменении структуры предложения его необособление становится **возможным.** Такое сравнение нужно для лучшего **понимания** темы.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Этот оборот упорно стремится быть обособленным, **но почему?**  Можно ли **вообще** его сделать **смысловым центром** высказывания и не обособлять? Трудно!

Поэтому допускается изобразить коммуникативную ситуацию другим описанием — **в двух фразах или в диалоге.** Обязательное условие — это отсутствие обособления и расположения определения **в постпозиции** к определяемому слову.

**[Розенталь, пункт 2 (2)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109)**

```
Не обособляются распространенные определения: 
2) стоящие после существительного, если последнее 
само по себе в данном предложении не выражает 
нужного смысла и нуждается в определении: 
Чернышевский создал произведение в высшей степени 
оригинальное (Д. П.);  Вернер — человек 
замечательный по многим причинам (Л);
```

Comment: Ну надо сначала про Вас, а потом про Нас, а если наоборот - то обособление.

Comment: Боюсь, что ничего не изменится) Но вы все-таки запишите свое предложение, а то не очень понятно.  Хорошо бы в поле ответа.

Comment: Да я не уверен, предположил). Ближайший к вАм наш офис находится...

Comment: Нет, так не говорят.   Можно разделить сообщение на две части, но речь должна быть естественной.  Мы ведь строим предложения и выбираем порядок слов по интуиции,  А по расстановке ударений чувствуем, какой вариант (обособленный или нет).  В исходном предложении явно нужно обособление.

Comment: Ну почему не говорят, когда как раз говорят, например в ответ кому-то. Вообще говорят без наш: ближайший к вам офис ... Ну или "наш ближайший к вам офис.." - тоже вроде без обособления или нет?

Comment: Нет, стилистика нехороша, не по-русски звучит. Представьте, что вы кому-то по телефону сообщаете нужные сведения.  Скомбинируйте иначе все эти слова.  Разделите на две фразы, если нужно.  Но чтобы предикация в предложении была одна, а не две.  И определение обязательно в постпозиции.  Уберите НАШ в другое предложение, если оно здесь вам мешает.  Главная задача - понять, как структура влияет на обособление.  Тогда можно придумывать предложения с обособлением или без обособления.

Comment: По мне, так: "наш офис", "наш" и "к вам" - уже не русская стилистика. Ближайший офис нашей фирмы находится ... - вот так по-русски.

Comment: Не понимаю, зачем перестраивать предложение, чтобы не обособлять его?

Comment: Для сравнения. Информация, которая то является смысловым центром, а то не является.

Answer (score 1):

**ОТВЕТ ЗАКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНЫЙ**

1. *Наш Офис, **ближАйший к вам**, находится на станции «Чёрная речка».* **Два ударения.**

**Обособленный оборот** — полупредикативная конструкция, аналог придаточного предложения. Здесь **два сообщения**: (1) Наш офис, находится на станции «Чёрная речка». (2) Этот офис — ближайший к вам. Какое из них **важнее** для клиента компании, пока сказать сложно. Это зависит от того, **какие сведения** он уже имеет.

2. В заданном предложении  дана информация **общего характера**, а теперь посмотрим, как меняется предложение **в диалоге.**

*— Ваш офис расположен у станции "Черная речка"? У вас только один офис?*

— *Нет, не один.  У «Черной речки»  находится  офис **ближайший  и более удОбный для вас**,  а вообще у нас несколько офисов.*
Ударение падает **на оборот.**

3. А **несогласованное** определение?

*Офис **из ближАйших к вам**  / находится на станции «Чёрная речка».*  Ударение падает **на оборот.**

Это определение не обособляется в данной позиции, хотя в других случаях может обособляться. В частности определение "наш" в препозиции способствует обособлению.

4. Мы видим, что **в моделях 2 и 3** оборот является смысловым центром **высказывания** (главное содержание), но также и смысловым центром  **предложения**, так как определение находится **в ударной позиции**. Именно по этому принципу и построены две эти  структурные модели: согласованное или несогласованное определение в позиции **логического выделения.**
5. А теперь самый Г**ЛАВНЫЙ СЕКРЕТ**. Простое предложение без обособления оборота должно иметь соответствующую **структуру,** то есть семантически и интонационно **делиться на две фразы** с  произносительной паузой между ними. Аналогично делится  и  сложное предложение. Если этого нет, то оборот **приходится обособлять**, а иначе предложение выглядит **стилистически некорректно,** например:  ***Наш офис ближАйший к вам** / находится на станции «Чёрная речка».*

При отсутствии слова «наш» предложение тоже звучит неестественно:  ***Офис ближАйший к вам** / находится на станции* «Чёрная речка».   Поэтому оборот и здесь нужно обособить.

6. **Вывод.** Итак, на первом месте **грамматика**, в том числе **интонационно-структурная** грамматика, а правила только следуют из нее. Правил достаточно в **стандартных** случаях, на это они и **рассчитаны**. Но если ситуация такой не является или если вам надо самим составить нужное предложение, то без интонационно-структурного анализа это сделать сложно. Да и правила лучше **понимать,**  а не просто заучивать.
7. **А в чем была ошибка?** Как раз в том, что структура заданного предложения **не соответствовала** интонации простого предложения. Это проверяется на слух: его **нельзя было разделить** произносительной паузой на две части **по смыслу, структуре и интонации.** И это касается любых предложений, где приходится **выбирать** между обособлением и необособлением.

Comment: Поддерживаю ваш ответ. Но! Стоит ли вдаваться в такие мельчайшие подробности в своих ответах? Нужно ли это простым  пользователям? Смогут ли они применять этот анализ? Думаю, нет...

Comment: Спасибо, Серж,  для меня очень важна ваша поддержка. В этой теме анализ оказался нужным для тех пользователей, которые очень внимательно изучают правила. Поэтому  нужно было объяснить отличие семантического центра высказывания от интонационного центра  предложения. Другими словам, если нужно  выделить смысл и логически его подчеркнуть, то это возможно в  моделях с ОДНИМ ударением на нужном слове, а для этого нужно подобрать структуру ПРОСТОГО предложения. Но в этой теме нет факультативного материала, всё предлагается решать по правилам.

Comment: Но есть темы, где в правилах говорится о ФАКУЛЬТАТИВНОСТИ обособления. Прежде всего,  это касается обстоятельственных оборотов на основе существительных. Есть и ДРУГИЕ темы, где по правилам обособление определить сложно, и поэтому приходится учитывать структуру предложения.  Вот пример. Нужно отличить придаточное от устойчивого оборота на его основе, и по этой теме задают очень много вопросов. И вот критерием для решения опять же является  структура ПРОСТОГО предложения. Другими словами, оборот должен ВПИСАТЬСЯ в простое предложение  (занять позицию одного слова).

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476936/Что-сможешь-запятые-с-двух-сторон  Этот момент в школьной программе никак не упоминается, а надо бы! Хотя бы в какой-то форме, к примеру, как элементарный анализ структуры предложений (тема и рема) для вопросов с обособлением конструкций.  Или самая простая качественная характеристика: это предложение нельзя прочитать как простое.

Comment: Шарон, со всем согласен. Но все смогут понять это. Вот в чем вопрос.

Comment: Возможно, и это для меня загадка.  Заколдованная тема! Достаточно, к примеру, посмотреть  вопрос  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463948/Не-могли-бы-вы-пояснить-что-такое-логическое-ударение-и-каковы-особенности-обос/463949?noredirect=1#comment514185_463949  А ведь этот участник очень старался понять интонационный анализ.  Грустная история. И Розенталь, как я думаю, понимал  важность интонации  (суперсегментный элемент, как-никак!), упоминал в отдельных темах, но рассказывать всё не считал своевременным. А иначе  будет такое отношение: «Философа Канта дразнили хануриком с детства…»))

Comment: Я тоже однажды пытался объяснить, что от интонации( а именно: от повышения и понижения голоса) в русском языке значение слова не меняется, все тщетно. Так что эта тема достаточна сложна для неподготовленных людей.

Comment: Значит, надо готовить. У меня весь материал по интонации в одном параграфе, вполне доступная информация, ничего сложного, для 6–7 класса подойдет. В школах по другим предметам такая сложная программа бывает, но изучается и понимается. А мы свой родной язык не хотим изучить.  Самые элементарные вещи не знаем. Вот еще тема: подробная информация о звуках, тоже все просто. Но почему-то нет этого в программе. А на этих знаниях многие орфограммы основаны, которые на пальцах объясняются.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна.По-моему, сомнений не должно быть.

Вот правило.

1. Обособляются (отделяются запятой, а в середине предложения выделяются с двух сторон запятыми) распространенные определения, выраженные причастием или прилагательным с зависящими от него словами (так называемые определительные обороты), стоящие после существительного или субстантивированного слова: По пыльной дороге, **ведущей к садам,** тянулись скрипучие арбы, **наполненные чёрным виноградом** (Л. Т.)

Для того чтобы не обособлять определение, оборот должен быть связан со сказуемым или существительное само по себе не должно выражать нужного смысла без оборота.

В нашем случае существительное без определительного оборота выражает нужный смысл.

Ср.:  Наш офис (ближайший к вам), находится на станции «Чёрная речка».

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150165/discussion-on-answer-by--------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0):

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ К ТЕМЕ** (еще одна практически такая же тема)

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476049/В-значении-близком-к-прямому](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476049/%D0%92-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83)

Почему возникли сомнения в правильности  написания текста **в правилах Розенталя?** Речь идет о следующем предложении:

*Сочетание «в свою очередь», если оно употреблено в значении, **близком к прямому**, или в значении "в ответ; со своей стороны", вводным не является.*

Здесь определительный оборот **обособляется**, но в вопросе обсуждается **правильность** обособления. Дается ответ, согласно которому текст Розенталя  записан **некорректно** (запятая не нужна), и этот ответ **принимается**. И только позже (где-то внизу, после долгих переговоров) автор ответа пишет, что запятая **все-таки нужна**.

Так почему возникают сомнения, **если их быть не должно?** Что именно не понимается в правиле?

**Конференция продолжается:**

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476635/У-Лео-и-Констанции-родился-ребёнок-больной-ВИЧом](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476635/%D0%A3-%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%92%D0%98%D0%A7%D0%BE%D0%BC)

— Нет оснований не ставить запятую. Определительный оборот **обособляется** по обычным правилам. Существительное не нуждается в этом определении, а оно само **смысловым центром не является.**

— Но тут же **главное — болезненность** ВИЧом!

Comment: @Серж,  Интересна точка зрения Максима, ведь это его ответ по тексту Розенталя. Сначала он не понимал про смысловой центр и дал этот ответ. После этого Лео тоже перестал понимать и отозвал мой ответ. Теперь Максим вроде бы понимает, а что понимает, я и не знаю.  Принимать участие в обсуждении не хочет. А в Сети висит решение, в котором говорится об ошибке. Поправка-дополнение видна плохо.  А ведь просили его исправить неправильное начало ответа.